How do I convert 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 to yyyymmdd in SQL using Case when?
I am a beginner and I use SQL Server and need help with converting date and time. How do I convert 2022-03-01 00:00:00.000 to yyyymmdd format using CASE WHEN?
I tried this:
FORMAT(pol_eff_dt, 'yyyymmdd')

but the results are 20220001 and I was expecting 20220301.
I appreciate any assistance that you can provide me.
Thank you!

Try yyyyMMdd instead. Also, it's all spelled out in the docs. Format is kinda slow though, i usually go for: convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)

What has this to do with a CASE expression?

Note that CONVERT with a style code is a far more performant metbodnif achieving this

TSQL FORMAT uses .NET format strings, which are documented here.  'm' is minute, 'M' is month.
So try 'yyyyMMdd' instead.
Alternativly use: convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)
